# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a binary file and save it as its original name on the disk.

I got the next error:

```
with open('%s.bin', 'wb') %name as f:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

```
import requests

f = open('test.txt')
tool = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()

params = {'apikey': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'hash': (tool)}
response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)

name = response.headers['x-goog-generation']
downloaded_file = response.content

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('%s.bin', 'wb') %name as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Move `%name` directly to the string. You are trying to replace something in a file object, but you have to do it at the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write:

```
with open('%s.bin', 'wb') % name as f:
```

since at that moment `open(..)`has been evaluated into a file handler. Here you thus basically write code that should evaluate the file handler *modulo* a string, and then enter this context manager.

You need to do the formatting at the string level, so:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('%s.bin' % name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```